# Chrome DevTools - Jquery y Bootstrap no cargan en simulación

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, google-chrome, optimización

Estoy haciendo pruebas para optimizar la carga de diferentes sitios, probando evitar el bloqueo de la carga del DOM por parte de CSS y JS.
Más allá del trabajo que ello conlleva, no logro ver las pruebas correctamente porque cada vez que recargo la página (con "disabled cache" y en "Slow 3G"), en cada vez, sea Jquery o Bootrap.min.js fallan en cargar.

No termino de entender porque, pero sinceramente, en CADA uno de los intentos alguno falla. Ésto me pasa para distintos sitios, en distintos hostings e incluso en localhost.

[image: Captura de DevTool cuando falla la carga de Jquery]

Agradezco su ayuda!

Ps. siguiente captura posterior al posteo aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]